# MySQL prevent data modification in one column with trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers, sql-update

I am trying to prevent a column from beign modified in an update. I have a column named `created_at` which is a timestamp but i want to put a lock on it.

I tried to create a `BEFORE UPDATE TRIGGER` without success.

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS Users_creation_update_exception;
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER Users_creation_update_exception
BEFORE UPDATE
ON `Users` FOR EACH ROW

    IF NEW.created_by <> (SELECT created_by FROM `Users` WHERE id = NEW.id LIMIT 1) THEN
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'; // It says error here
    END IF;

END//
DELIMITER ;
```

I don't know if triggers are the right answer for this kind of problem. I have put on my `FORIGN KEY` a `ON UPDATE NO ACTION`. I would like a similar behavior.

I looked for information in the `SIGNAL` page of [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/signal.html). It is the same on [MariaDB `SIGNAL` page](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/signal/).

I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

I'm on phpmyadmin through XAMPP with

- Server type: MariaDB
- Server version: 10.1.21-MariaDB - mariadb.org binary distribution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```sql
MariaDB [_]> SELECT VERSION();
+----------------+
| VERSION()      |
+----------------+
| 10.2.7-MariaDB |
+----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [_]> DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Users`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [_]> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Users` (
    ->   `id` BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    ->   `created_by` DATETIME NOT NULL
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [_]> DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `Users_creation_update_exception`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [_]> DELIMITER //

MariaDB [_]> CREATE TRIGGER `Users_creation_update_exception`
    -> BEFORE UPDATE ON `Users`
    -> FOR EACH ROW
    -> BEGIN
    ->   IF TRUE THEN
    ->     SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
    ->       SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'An error occurred';
    ->   END IF;
    -> END//
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [_]> DELIMITER ;

MariaDB [_]> INSERT INTO `Users`
    -> VALUES (NULL, NOW());
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [_]> UPDATE `Users` SET `created_by` = NOW();
ERROR 1644 (45000): An error occurred
```

Comment: I can see that I forgot to write `BEGIN`

Comment: I will update as soon as I will get home. I'll give you feed back then.